# Can I store a text file in a tarball in an image`s EXIF data?

Tags: tar, exif

I am working on creating an Easter egg for a website.  I want to hide some lines of data in an image`s EXIF comment field which can be used to reconstitute a tarball that contains a text file with a riddle.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I get the code/data for the tarball which I can then include in the EXIF data?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, although you may have to encode the data (e.g. using base64) if you use a field intended to hold ASCII text.

The best way to generate a tarball is to use the appropriately-named `tar` utility.

Comment: So if I have a tarball on my computer, how do I get the actual string of data that composs the tarbal so that I can insert it into the EXIF field?

Comment: The same way you'd read any other data file in your language of choice, e.g. `fopen` in C, or perhaps `file_get_contents` in PHP.

Comment: And how would the finder of that string reconstitute it into a usable  tarball ?

Comment: By doing the reverse of whatever you do to insert it: extract the comment field, base64-decode it (if you encoded it), and untar.